# Does asmack has the extension jar similar to smackx?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, google-talk, asmack

I am trying to create multi user google talk client for android. With asmack i am able to set it up to run user-user chat. Now when i am trying to create a group chat i am getting exceptions related to smackx missing.
When i try adding smackx jar I am getting the following error,
"Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1"

Answer (score 0):

There are many incarnations of asmack. Which one did you use? But IIRC all include the extensions provided by smackx. Sounds like you forgot to register the extensions with the ProviderManager. See the section "ProviderManager" [in the Readme.](https://github.com/Flowdalic/asmack)